# How use # in android adt?

Tags: android

I have an application who compose code and call but # DOESN't work it compose just *710

```
Intent appel = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("tel:*710#"));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending ACTION\_CALL Intent in Android containing hash # sign](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7280209/sending-action-call-intent-in-android-containing-hash-sign)

Answer (score 0):

Encoding the uri for `#` before passing for parsing solves the problem.

```
String uri = "tel:*710%23";
Intent appel = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse(uri));
```

Comment: there is an error The method encode(String) is undefined for the type String